# include background image using javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to apply background image with no repeat using javascript..

```
#img_name{

    background-image:
    background-repeat:
}
```

how to convert this accordingly

```
 $("#img_name").html("<img src=assets/\images\/"+data['img_name']+">");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#img_name').css('background-image', 'url("assets/images/"'+data['img_name']+'")');
$('#img_name').css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
```

Or, setting both in one go:

```
$('#img_name').css({
    'background-image' : 'url("/assets/images/'+data['img_name']+'")',
    'background-repeat': 'no-repeat'
});
```

Comment: it must be from `<?php echo data['img_name']; ?>`. Replace it with a value. You can't run PHP in a .js file (or test the script in a .php file)

Comment: try `'url("assets/images/"'+data['img_name']+'")'`

Comment: You can't set CSS properties trough `html()`. That's what `css()` is for.